# Skobbler API's issue during rerouting

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, skmaps

I am using skobbler API for my iOS application. Once I give the source and destination points for route drawing, it works fine and navigations are also working as expected. During navigation I am facing very random and strange issue, my application is getting stucked in internal threads and is not responding.

During Navigation, Application is only getting crashed for some routes and getting stuck in thread

Thread 4: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x0)

0 Router::RouteToTrack(CRoute*, SSegmentForRoutingMatching const&, int, int, bool, bool, int&)

1 Router::CreateImposedRouteImpl(std::tr1::shared_ptr&, bool, bool)

2 Router::CreateImposedRouteImpl(std::tr1::shared_ptr&, bool, bool)

3 RouteManager::computeRouteFromTrack(SRouteManagerInput&, std::tr1::shared_ptr&, std::vector, std::allocator > >&)

4 RouteManager::run()

5 RouteManager::run()

6 _pthread_start

Below is the location coordinates i am using for Navigation
Source : 41.847819, -87.666715
Destination : 41.860881, -87.693194

This scenario is only happening for certain points, for rest of the locations navigation is perfect!

Please suggest something, I have been looking for a solution from a long time.

Here is the code to fetch and draw route.

```
          for (SKGPSFileElement *s in routingArray) {
                            if(s.type == SKGPSFileElementGPXTrack)
                            {
                                index++;
                                if(self.trackArray != nil && self.isRouteCalculated == YES)
                                {
                                    __block BOOL sameArray = NO;
                                    for (CLLocation *l in [[SKGPSFilesService sharedInstance] locationsForElement:s]) {
                                        sameArray = NO;
                                        [self.trackArray enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(CLLocation *obj, NSUInteger index, BOOL *stop){
                                            if(l.coordinate.latitude == obj.coordinate.latitude && l.coordinate.longitude == obj.coordinate.longitude)
                                            {
                                                *stop = YES;
                                                sameArray = YES;

                                            }
                                        } ];

                                        if(sameArray == NO)
                                            break;
                                    }

                                    if(sameArray == NO)
                                    {
                                         @synchronized([SKRoutingService sharedInstance]){
                                            SKRouteSettings* route = [[SKRouteSettings alloc]init];
                                            route.shouldBeRendered = YES; // If NO, the route will not be rendered.
                                            route.requestAdvices = YES;
                                            route.numberOfRoutes = 1;
                                            [[SKRoutingService sharedInstance]calculateRouteWithSettings:route GPSFileElement:s];
                                        } 
                                    }

                                 }
```

Comment: Please add also the code snippet that you are using to create the route

Comment: An issue has been reported to the dev team -we're waiting for their answer

Comment: Thank you Ando. Lemme know. :)

Comment: I have updated the SKMaps framework for iOS to 2.2 and it seems the thread stuck issue is handled, instead of app getting stucked the navigation stops in between and i get the message "GPX track navigation is available for commercial use with a enterprise license" in the console.

Comment: The console message is normal - the app navigation stop is not (is a log message, not a breakpoint) - can you check to see if the app runs smoothly without breakpoints?

Answer (score 0):

This is what Skobller has to say. Can't say I think it's a valid answer...

> All UI-related operations (including rendering) must be done on Main thread, so there's nothing we can do about this. 
>   Talking into consideration the provided details we cannot suggest any workarounds.
>   If the timers are needed at app startup, maybe you can initialize the framework later, but that depends on your internal logic.

http://forum.skobbler.com/archive/index.php/t-7428.html